# How to make a widget that its children can expand over its parent not in the same stack?

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField which as I type in it consults a cities database and the results are shown in a ListView just like a Google Maps search box. In a attempt to make the results to hover over other elements I've tried to add the listview in a stack with clip behavior set to "none" and various other configurations but I still couldn't managed to make the results hover over the page. I intend to use it for flutter web and there will be other elements which the search results cannot displace them to fit the query. I could access a parent Stack and pass the position of the TextFormField so I would know where to build the result list but this tinkering its not very straight forward so I was wondering if I could punch a hole in the parent layer from a child to print the result list.

Comment: what you need is `Overlay` widget

Comment: for example see how `Autocomplete` widget do that: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f1875d570e39de09040c8f79aa13cc56baab8db1/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/autocomplete.dart

Comment: Post as an answer so I can mark as correct. That's exactly what I needed. For future reference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OOEyJ0ct0Sg. Thank you.

Comment: your welcome, feel free to post a self-answer then :-)